# Cypher Query returning more edge types than asked for

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Schema:

- Users create ChatItems
- ChatItems are in response to other ChatItems
- ChatItems can mentions Users.

The length of the longest chatItem reponse Chain is 9.

I have the following query

```
MATCH p=(i1:ChatItem)-[:ResponseTo*]->(i2:ChatItem) WHERE length(p) = 9 
WITH [i in nodes(p)] as items
MATCH path=(u:User)-[:CreateChat]->(i:ChatItem)
WHERE i IN items
RETURN DISTINCT path
```

This should basically return all the `UserNodes-CreateChatEdge->ChatItemNodes` such that those ChatItemNodes are from the longest chatItem chain right?

But what I actually get is a graph of the longest ChatItem chain(i.e with the `ResponseTo` edges which are not part of the final `MATCH`) AND Which User created which ChatItem, but ALSO which Users are MentionedBy which ChatItem.

This is surprising to me as the `Mentioned` edge is not mentioned anywhere in the query.
Output Image:
[image]

I was expecting is the same graph but without the `ResponseTo` and the `Mentioned` edges.
It is clear that I am a noob when it comes to CypherQueries, any help or explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are hitting a Neo4j Browser configuration issue. By default, the browser shows all relationships between the resulting nodes. You can disable this configuration in the "Browser settings tab":

[image]

Comment: What changes will I have to make to my original query to make it return the the image in the question?

Comment: If you disable this option, and still want all relationships, you'll have to remove the filter on the relationship type in your query, to return all paths, regardless of the relationship type.